# HTML5 Canvas strokeStyle from createPattern

Tags: html, canvas

Then i use big canvas images and createPattern for strokestyle i have lags.
Have two styles: pencil and eraser (eraser is style createrPattern from other canvas)

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/y059fujd/

This is code place then i create pattern of style:

```
$("#eraser").click(function() {
    ctx.lineWidth = 5;
    ctx.globalCompositeOperation = "source-over"; 
    ctx.strokeStyle = ctx.createPattern(canvasBig, 'no-repeat');    
});
```

Answer (score 0):

There are in fact several issues in your code :
- canvasBig is too big, which slows down and may even break on some browser/devices.
- You are creating a pattern on each button click : Be aware that creating a pattern requires to copy the content since it might change afterwise. So there's heavy useless work ongoing here.
- The various image/canvas size didn't match, so the erasing could not work.
- I don't get why you need 3 canvas for a draw area + a backup, but i guess you'll use later the big canvas for some other thing. Best is to already make draw/erase work fine before this new feature.

All this is fixed here :

http://jsfiddle.net/y059fujd/4/

```
var img = new Image();
img.onload = function () {
    ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0, img.width, img.height);
    ctxBackup.drawImage(img, 0, 0, 700, 500);
    imgPattern = ctx.createPattern(img, "no-repeat");
};

// 
$("#eraser").click(function () {
    ctx.lineWidth = 5;
    ctx.globalCompositeOperation = "source-over";
    ctx.strokeStyle = imgPattern;
});
```

Comment: I need backup's because i used zoom. Me zoom is image.width * scale and image.height * scale